# Finding month-wise records for each month in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table from which i need to fine month-wise records and i am using the following query

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(date_created) as mon,count(`activity_id`) as tot,CASE status 
        WHEN '5' THEN 'Submitted'
        WHEN '2' THEN 'Contacted'
        WHEN '10' THEN 'Placed'
        WHEN '7' THEN 'Offered'
        WHEN '9' THEN 'DECLINED'
        END as status 
        FROM activity WHERE entered_by = '65' GROUP BY mon,`status`
```

The outcome of the above query is giving each month's record as following

```
        **mon**           **tot**            **status**
        Aug                  2                Submitted
        Aug                  3                Placed
        Sep                  3                Contacted
```

Now i want the record for each month like if a table does not contain any record for the month of Jan then output should like as following

```
          **mon**           **tot**            **status**
        Jan                  0                Submitted
        Jan                  0                Placed
        Jan                  0                Contacted
        Jan                  0                Declined
```

How can i do this??

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: does table have record entry for month jan, or if even month jan is not included in table, despite you need to show month jan.

Comment: No, Table don't have record for month Jan, Yes i want 0 as (tot) value for Jan if there is no record of Jan.

Comment: look for query which returns all months name from jan to dec. and use join query with your query. it may help you

Comment: I have tried by taking a reference table of month and then using left join but still it does not return the expected outcome.. Any Guess :(

Comment: did you try full outer join?